# How to capitalize particular elements in list (python)

Tags: python, list

I wish to take user input and get 2d list searched; how to use 2d list and get input?

Comment: The easiest way to code it would be a brute force search through every row and column. I doubt that you'll need to efficiency of complicated pattern matching algorithms. If you have a crack with the brute force method and still have problems feel free to post your attempt and we can help then.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
letters = [['l', 'd', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'p'],  
    ['i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'f'],   
    ['g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'u'],  
    ['h', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'l'],  
    ['t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'l'],   
    ['d', 'r', 'a', 'w', 'c', 's']]

words = ['draw', 'full', 'hold', 'laugh', 'light', 'start', 'all', 'kid']

word = words[0]
splitted_word = list(word)
for i in range(len(letters)):
    if set(splitted_word).difference(set(letters[i])) == set():
        letters[i] = [x.upper() if  x in splitted_word else x for x in letters[i]]

print(letters)
```

just substitute the `word` variable by the one you are looking for.

Comment: Oh!, now I see... sorry, I didn't realise it... well, this is a tough one... It will demand some hours of coding...

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is to create functions to rearrange the letters in lists that shows all ways you could find a word. E.g. reverse vertical, horizontal, reverse horizontal, etc... try this rearrengements one by one with patiance... each arrengement is a question by it self.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like this:

```
for i in matrix:
    line = ''.join(i)
    x = line.find(word) #word is the word we need to search eg. draw
    if x != -1:
        i[x:len(word)].upper()
```

I am not sure if it'll work i havent tested it. Lemme know if this helps.